# DataTables: Cannot read property style of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, datatables

I am getting this error with the following:

```
jquery.dataTables.js:4089 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined(…)
_fnCalculateColumnWidths @ jquery.dataTables.js:4089
_fnInitialise @ jquery.dataTables.js:3216
(anonymous function) @ jquery.dataTables.js:6457
each @ jquery-2.0.2.min.js:4
each @ jquery-2.0.2.min.js:4
DataTable @ jquery.dataTables.js:5993
$.fn.DataTable @ jquery.dataTables.js:14595
(anonymous function) @ VM3329:1
(anonymous function) @ VM3156:180
l @ jquery-2.0.2.min.js:4
fireWith @ jquery-2.0.2.min.js:4
k @ jquery-2.0.2.min.js:6
(anonymous function) @ jquery-2.0.2.min.js:6
```

The line above referring to     (anonymous function) @ VM3156:180 is:

```
                TASKLISTGRID = $("#TASK_LIST_GRID").DataTable({
                    data : response,
                    columns : columns.AdoptionTaskInfo.columns,
                    paging: true
                });
```

So I am guessing this is where it is failing.

The HTML ID element exist:

```
  <table id="TASK_LIST_GRID" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="TASK_LIST_GRID_info">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Solution</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Status</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Category</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Type</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Due Date</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Create Date</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Owner</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Comments</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Mnemonic</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Domain</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Approve</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Dismiss</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Also, the columns.AdoptionTaskInfo.columns & response object arrays exist. Not sure how to debug what's wrong.. Any suggestions will be helpful..

Comment: Look for `.style` in your code. You're trying to access that property of an undefined variable. You can debug from there.

Comment: Check if the number of columns you're trying to fetch is same as the number of <th> you've created.

Comment: Number of th column mismatch with number of columns defined in javascripts causing this issue.

Answer (score 425):

The problem is that the number of <th> tags need to match the number of columns in the configuration (the array with the key "columns"). If there are fewer <th> tags than columns specified, you get this slightly cryptical error message.

(the correct answer is already present as a comment but I'm repeating it as an answer so it's easier to find - I didn't see the comments)

Comment: i want add another point, may be people find it helpful in somecase, if you don't define dataSrc then in your json use "data", if you use another name you will get this error.

Comment: Also, if you have columns that are not visible but included for things like searching or the Editor, they must be at the end of your columns:[ ]  list.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was wondering issues in javascripts..

Comment: Thanks, i also found i was getting my data wrongly and had less fileds than columns, so this made me found out more than one error I got

Comment: you need to get an award. Saved Ton of time. Thank you @ehrencrona

Comment: missed closing h> not closed after <t in one of the def

Answer (score 64):

#### POSSIBLE CAUSES

- Number of `th` elements in the table header or footer differs from number of columns in the table body or defined using [`columns`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns) option.
- Attribute colspan is used for `th` element in the table header.
- Incorrect column index specified in [`columnDefs.targets`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets) option.

#### SOLUTIONS

- Make sure that number of `th` elements in the table header or footer matches number of columns defined in the [`columns`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns) option.
- If you use `colspan` attribute in the table header, make sure you have at least two header rows and one unique `th` element for each column. See [Complex header](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html) for more information.
- If you use [`columnDefs.targets`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets) option, make sure that zero-based column index refers to existing columns.

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables: Common JavaScript console errors - TypeError: Cannot read property ‘style’ of undefined](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-common-javascript-console-errors/#typeerror-cannot-read-property-style-of-undefined) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the last solution of column index helped me

Answer (score 19):

most of the time it happens when the table header count and data cel count is not matched

Answer (score 17):

You said any suggestions wold be helpful, so currently I resolved my DataTables "cannot read property 'style' of undefined" problem but my problem was basically using wrong indexes at data table initiation phase's `columnDefs` section. I got 9 columns and the indexes are 0, 1, 2, .. , 8 but I was using indexes for 9 and 10 so after fixing the wrong index issue the fault has disappeared. I hope this helps.

In short, you got to watch your columns amount and indexes if consistent everywhere.

**Buggy Code:**

```
    jQuery('#table').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            url: "something_url",
            type: 'POST'
        },
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "cl1" },
            { "data": "cl2" },
            { "data": "cl3" },
            { "data": "cl4" },
            { "data": "cl5" },
            { "data": "cl6" },
            { "data": "cl7" },
            { "data": "cl8" },
            { "data": "cl9" }
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            { orderable: false, targets: [ 7, 9, 10 ] } //This part was wrong
        ]
    });
```

**Fixed Code:**

```
    jQuery('#table').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            url: "something_url",
            type: 'POST'
        },
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "bPaginate": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "cl1" },
            { "data": "cl2" },
            { "data": "cl3" },
            { "data": "cl4" },
            { "data": "cl5" },
            { "data": "cl6" },
            { "data": "cl7" },
            { "data": "cl8" },
            { "data": "cl9" }
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            { orderable: false, targets: [ 5, 7, 8 ] } //This part is ok now
        ]
    });
```

Comment: This saved me, thanks.
I use "aTargets": [7], so its go to error, cuz there doesn't exists column with index 7.
http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns

Comment: Great I am happy that my answer fixed your issue,  + votes please

Answer (score 14):

For me the data columns `{data: columnName}` had more columns
than Table Heads `<th>Column Name</th>`

Comment: Excellent My Brother!...
My THead is 26 and the grid columns 27

Answer (score 12):

I had this issue when i set `colspan` in table header. So my table was:

```
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Expenses</th>

                <th colspan="2">Income</th>

                <th>Profit/Loss</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

Then once i change it to:

```
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Expenses</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Income</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>Profit/Loss</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

Everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that in your input data, `response[i]` and `response[i][j]`, are not `undefined`/`null`.

If so, replace them with "".

Answer (score 3):

It can also happen when drawing a new (other) table. I solved this by first removing the previous table:

`$("#prod_tabel_ph").remove();`

Answer (score 2):

The solution is pretty simple.

```html
  <table id="TASK_LIST_GRID" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer" width="100%" role="grid" aria-describedby="TASK_LIST_GRID_info">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Solution</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Status</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Category</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Type</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Due Date</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Create Date</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Owner</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Comments</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Mnemonic</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Domain</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Approve</th>
      <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="TASK_LIST_GRID" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Dismiss</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

```js
                TASKLISTGRID = $("#TASK_LIST_GRID").DataTable({
                    data : response,
                    columns : columns.AdoptionTaskInfo.columns,
                    paging: true
                });
                
                //Note: columns : columns.AdoptionTaskInfo.columns has at least a column not definded in the <thead>
```

**Note**: columns : columns.AdoptionTaskInfo.columns has at least a column not defined in the table head

Answer (score 2):

The answers here put me on the right path, but none gave me the full answer I needed. I was using `destroy: true` as an option, but on a second iteration of a DataTable, I kept getting the error in the original question.

Instead, I had to call the `destroy()` method directly, **and** clear out the child entities of the HTML to force DataTables to properly repaint the DataTable on each iteration without a conflict between the `<th>` headers and the ones being passed in `columns:` like this:

```js
if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#results_table')) {
    $('#results_table').DataTable().destroy();
}
$('#results_table thead').empty();
$('#results_table tbody').empty();

$('#results_table').DataTable({
    data: data,
    columns: columns,
    ...etc...
});
```

Comment: Correct My Brother! But the THead is missing how?

Answer (score 1):

Funnily i was getting the following error for having one th-/th pair too many and still google directed me here. I'll leave it written down so people can find it.

```
jquery.dataTables.min.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined
at ua (jquery.dataTables.min.js:27)
at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:127)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.j (jquery.dataTables.min.js:116)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (history:619)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was updating the server-sided datatable twice and it gives me this error. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error, by replacing the src attribute with https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js, the problem is caused by the slim version of JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with  Jquery Datatable. The number of table head ( tags) in table heading was same with  tags in table body. I resolved this issue by removing one of the Datatable attribute called "scrollX": true". Then everything works fine for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
"aoColumns": [{
               "bVisible": false, 
               "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) 
                {},
             ]
```

I solved this issue by setting bVisible as false. You can also set condition on bVisible as "bVisible": var1, where var1 can be true or false;

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by setting `bVisible` as `false`. You can also set condition on `bVisible` as `"bVisible": var1`, where `var1` can be `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was because I did not have the required "data" wrapper.

Wrap your JSON in this:

```
{ 
"data": [
{your app data here},...{}
]}
```

Once I did that, the issue was resolved.